# POST and GET executing simultaneously in MVC 4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to edit a field after clicking an item from a table.

I added an on clcik event to every object in the table like this :

```
onclick="itemEdit(this)
```

And my javascript function looks something like :

```
  function itemEdit(e) {
        console.log($(e).attr("id"));
        var itmId = $(e).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Scraping")',
            data: {itemId: itmId},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

And what I do in my Index method is to load the clicked item in a more detailed manner on the top of the page like this :

```
 public ActionResult Index(string itemId)
        {
            if (itemId != null)
            {
                im.loadItem(itemId.ToString());

            }
            else
            {
                if (im.lstEditModel.Count == 0)
                {
                    im.loadLists();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

The problem I am having is that whenever I click an item, the index method executes twice..and thus creating a mess. Any help?

Comment: do you have the `[HttpPost]` attribute on that action?

Comment: @Jonesy If he hadn't, he'd have a redirect loop on his hands.

Comment: How did you add it to every item?  JavaScript events bubble up the object hierarchy.  So onclick on cells bubble to rows bubble to the table etc.  If Onclick is on cells and rows and table then it will fire multiple times per click.

Comment: Can you show the table markup and both GET and POST action methods?

Comment: plus I don't think the ajax call would find the action, true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an `[HttpPost]` mark on that method, but at the end of the method, you are redirecting to another `Index` action... you normally would return some sort of JSON data rather than  `return RedirectToAction("Index");`... this statement would be doing what you are describing, calling your Get Action.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop event bubbling.

```
function itemEdit(e) {

e.stopPropagation();       

console.log($(e).attr("id"));
        var itmId = $(e).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Scraping")',
            data: {itemId: itmId},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this, by mistake I forgot to put href="#" when adding the onClick event causing the browser to reload my javascript code. I had typed href=""